# VBA Solver loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, solver

I am using Solver with the following code:

```
Sub Test()

  SolverReset

  SolverOk SetCell:="$K$7", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$I$7:$J$7", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

  SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$7", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$H$7"
  SolverAdd CellRef:="$K$7", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$B$7"

  SolverSolve UserFinish:=False

  SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

End Sub
```

I now need to put it into a loop in order to run Solver from row 7 to row 17. I coded it as per the below but it doesn't work:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 7 To 17
  SolverReset

  SolverOk SetCell:="$K$" & i, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$I$ & i:$J$ & i", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

  SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$" & i, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$H$" & i
  SolverAdd CellRef:="$K$" & i, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$B$" & i

  SolverSolve UserFinish:=False

  SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

Next i  

End sub
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" should be added to censored list... Can you explain more detailed what result are you getting - is it a compilation error, runtime exception or anything else?

Comment: It worked without the loop so it seems to be a compilation error (I am not sure about the correct syntax of the ByChange function).

Comment: so that's it, you have missed double quotes in that place - ByChange:="$I$ & i:$J$ & i" and you should use ByChange:="$I$" & i & ":$J$" & i  Try and let me know if it was an issue.

Comment: That was the issue, with your syntax (ByChange:="$I$" & i & ":$J$" & i) everything works fine

Comment: Great news! Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ...

```
Dim i             As Long

For i = 7 To 17
  SolverReset

  With Rows(i)
    SolverOk SetCell:=.Range("K1").Address, _
             MaxMinVal:=1, _
             ByChange:=.Range("I1:J1").Address, _
             Engine:=1
    SolverAdd CellRef:=.Range("G1").Address, _
              Relation:=2, _
              FormulaText:=.Range("H1").Address
    SolverAdd CellRef:=.Range("K1").Address, _
              Relation:=2, _
              FormulaText:=.Range("B1").Address
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
  End With
Next i
```